# Color applied via CSS shows different on IE & Chrome

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, css, design

Color applied via CSS shows different on IE & Chrome for SPS2013.

**Example:** I've set the base colour as blue using a content editor for a specific SPS page.

However, on IE it shows white, while Chrome shows blue and few other machines with chrome shows it as black.

Wondering what I can do to main uniformity.

Any ideas?

Comment: interesting, what ie browser version are you using to test and what versions of OS are being used?? you need to use F12 developer tools to inspect the element to see what css is applied to the control.

Comment: Determine where the 3 different colors come from, then try to figure out what You are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is really awesome....you are doing something wrong...Try putting condition over your CSS and then check:

```
if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("chrome")>-1) {
document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="../component/chromeCSSStyles.css" />');
} else if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("mozilla")>-1) {
    document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="../component/mozillaStyles.css" />');
} else if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("explorer")>-1) {
    document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="../component/explorerStyles.css" />');
}
```

Comment: Sorry for acting DUMB.

Ankit, how shall I add the above condition on my Intranet page to test.

Comment: before adding you should have those css files in the location specified in href.. or store the css files in a particular library in sharepoint site and provide the links in here